# PhoneNumberUtils is not formatting some numbers

Tags: android

I need to format the number to x xxx xxx xx-xx. Here is two examples.

```
PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber("+79998887766", "RU"))
```

Result is: "+7 999 888-77-66". This is what I need.

```
PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber("+71112223344", "RU"))
```

Result is: "+71112223344". The number with same length is not formatted.

How to format the second number?

Comment: It almost impossible. Have you tried clean and rebuild project?

Comment: @Mij Yes, you can try this on a new project. I think it has something to do with carrier codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The second number you are passing is not valid.**

[Google provides a library for formatting and validating the phone numbers.](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber)

**Add below dependency into your app-level build.gradle inside `dependencies{}`:**

```
compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.2.2'
```

**Example :**

```java
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
boolean isValid;
String no;
try {
    Phonenumber.PhoneNumber numberProto = phoneUtil.parse("+79112223344", "RU"); // Pass number & Country code
    //check whether the number is valid or not.
    isValid = phoneUtil.isValidNumber(numberProto);
    if (isValid) {
        no = phoneUtil.format(numberProto, PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL);
        System.out.println("Formatted Number :" + no);
    } else
        System.out.println("Invalid Number");
} catch (NumberParseException e) {
    System.err.println("NumberParseException was thrown: " + e.toString());
}
```

[For more info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Russia)

Comment: Thank you, I see the problem now, but how can I format the invalid number? I don't want to depend on the user's locale, I want to format any number.

Comment: In that case, You need to write your own method.